# How to select the same column from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, select

I have 2 tables as follows, with the same columns

```
Table 1
Name             Subject
Alan Smith       Biology
Fred Jones       Biology
Anne Pool        Chemistry


Table 2
Name             Subject
Paul Jones       Chemistry 
Ted Williams     Biology
```

Question: What `SELECT` statement will retrieve just rows where **Subject** is **Biology** from the 2 tables?

Comment: How are you linking the 2 tables? A WHERE clause = 'Biology' would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Name 
FROM table2 
WHERE Subject='Biology' 
    UNION SELECT Name 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE Subject='Biology'
```

[UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) combines the result sets from multiple `SELECT` statements, while using it, the columns in both tables have to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Perform two `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE subject = 'biology'` queries on each table and handle that data.

Comment: OP said from both tables. He needs a join